# Tests never get executed because of the Mockito.doThrow

Tags: android, testing, android-asynctask, mockito, android-testing

I am testing an anroid app using `Mockito`. I want to test an exception case, but the method `Mockito.doThrow` hangs and the test never gets executed (it neither fails nor succeeds).

Here's the code. `PackageDownloader` represents an `AsyncTask`. Its method `get` gets called inside of the `downloadPackage` method. But the execution never comes to that point because it hangs exactly on `doThrow` line.

```
PackageDownloader packageDownloader = new PackageDownloader();
PackageDownloader mockPackageDownloader = Mockito.spy(packageDownloader);
HttpURLConnection connectionMock = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
Mockito.doReturn(connectionMock)
       .when(mockPackageDownloader)
       .createConnection(Mockito.any(URL.class));
Mockito.doThrow(new InterruptedException()).when(mockPackageDownloader).get();
downloadPackage();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out I was trying to stub a final method (which is, if you look at the definition, `AsyncTask.get()`).
With Mockito, it's impossible to mock final methods.
The problem is I wasn't able to find out why the code hangs, and this is certainly a Mockito fault.

I found out the issue by placing `doThrow` after the `downloadPackage` method call.